# libopencv_optflow possibly does not contain all the function definitions that are specified inside optflow.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv

I have installed **OpenCV 4.0**, and in Makefile I have specified the path to opencv extra modules, but when I try to run my **GoLang** project which is using OpenCV function created in **C++** (I have wrapped **C++** code in **C** library which I included in **GoLang**) I get *"undefined reference error".*

Thing is, when I position myself at `/usr/local/include` there is `optflow.hpp` file which contains function declaration that I need, but my `/usr/local/src` folder, which is where source files should be located I assume, is empty. Or there are no source files at all and all of them have been built into `/usr/local/lib`, in which case I am still not sure why I get ***"undefined reference"*** error message.

Is it possible that optflow.hpp and libopencv_optflow library that has been built, are not compatable? If so, how can I fix it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: "installed OpenCV 4.0, and in Makefile I have specified the path to opencv extra modules" -- can you elaborate on that? I understand installing as deploying the already built binaries and headers (but no source files). From what I've seen "setting path to opencv extra" is something you do with CMake before you build OpenCV (the that the result includes the extra modules).

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to use Cmake to configure parameters of building and linking. This kind of problem can occur due to -std=c++11, but Cmake prepares very complex set up for your make files and typical result is problems like yours and cannot find imread and more. I have lots of trouble to set up make files for opencv 4 for building project directly from visual studio [visual studio](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2019/02/opencv-4-linux-application-in-visual.html?m=1)

Another think is linked libs. You can miss something from the dynamic dependencies used by the opencv lib.   Cmake solves this configuration for you.

g++" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-pointer-sign" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -std=c++11 -w -fno-strict-aliasing -I "/usr/local/include/opencv4/opnecv2" -g0 "g++" -O2 "3600000" -fno-threadsafe-statics -D "NDEBUG" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -fno-rtti -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c11 -fno-exceptions "1" -o r

And linker parameters as

```
Linker opencv 4 configuration part is more tricky
```

Library dependencies -l"opencv_core" -l"opencv_imgcodecs" -l"opencv_imgproc" -l"opencv_video" -l"opencv_videoio" -l"pthread" -l"jpeg" -l"gcc_s" -l"stdc++" -l"tbb" -l"rt" -l"dl" -l"m" -l"z" -l"png16" -l"c"

You are just filling following values into Library dependencies option without -l 
opencv_core
opencv_imgcodecs
opencv_imgproc
opencv_video
opencv_videoio
pthread
jpeg
gcc_s
stdc++
tbb
rt
dl
m
z
png16
c

Comment: in /usr/local/lib there are 3x different library builds: libopencv_optflow.so , libopencv_optflow.so.4.0, libopencv_optflow.so.4.0.0 . Which one do I actually need, and if it is one of the last two, how do I specify it with '-l' command? Like, lopencv_optflow.4.0.0? Where does the .so extension go?

Comment: Like in example -l"opencv_optflow"   You just need: opencv_optflow  no lib before, no so.4.0 after.  Problem can be other dependency (libs) used by optflow lib. Opencv 4 -std=c++11 this can be issue as well.